# Image uploaded but dimensions still the same of source

Tags: php, upload, dimensions

```
if ( $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/png" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/gif" ) 
{
    if ($_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/png" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/gif" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["ufile"]["type"] [$i] == "image/jpg" ) 
    {
        $file=$_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
        $new_width = 200;
        $new_height = 500;
        $dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
        $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"]);
        imagecopyresized ($dst_image, $src_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($dst_image)), "convert.jpg");
        $actual_image_name = $name[$i].'.'.'jpg';
        move_uploaded_file("convert.jpg", $path.$actual_image_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the question anywhere hidden in the code? Does i have to search for it?

Comment: **NEVER** use the `['type']` field for validation. it's trivial to forget. Since you're using getimagesize(), just use its `['mime']` parameter to see what the file really is.

Comment: first move uploaded file and then apply dimension changes

Answer (score 0):

You are totally mis-using GD. `$dst_image` is a GD image handle. It is *not* a file. So... `file_get_contents()` will return boolean FALSE, since you're trying to fetch from something that is *not* a filename. `imagecreatefromstring()` will return boolean false, since a boolean false is *not* an image string, and `imagejpeg()` will return boolean FALSE since you're not passing it a GD Handle.

In short, your code could do with some improvement. You simply assume nothing could ever go wrong, don't ever check for failure, and those failures propagate onwards through the code.

All you really needed was

```
image_jpeg($dst_image, 'convert.jpg');
```

And then your `move_uploaded_file` will *also*  fail, since "convert.jpg" isn't an uploaded file. It's a file you've created yourself on the server. It may have been based on an uploaded file, but in and of itself is *not* an uploaded file. Why not just

```
image_jpeg($dst_image, "$path/$actual_image_name");
```

Comment: I thought the commentary in this answer was a bit sharp, so I've made it a bit softer, whilst hopefully conveying the same meaning. The OP will be long gone, but I think there's value in being kind to future readers who may also be beginner devs!